# HTML5 canvas javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, brush

i have brush with transparency mode i need while drawing on the top get darker like this: [image]

Now while painting on the top i get same color like this: 
[image]

```js
var el = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');

ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.globalAlpha = "0.2";
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";

var isDrawing, points = [ ];

el.onmousedown = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
};

el.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
  for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
};

el.onmouseup = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
  points.length = 0;
};
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid #ccc }
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How to create paint brush like a first picture example

Comment: This might push you in the right direction http://jsfiddle.net/ne0e840h/ ,when you stay on or go over a red parts it draws a new circle over it making the red more visible

Comment: the same thing but with more of your code http://jsfiddle.net/2uhdcn0r/

Comment: dwana now the brush is not smooth, now only see circles.. this is not good..

Comment: Sorry for my not civility :D thanks for trying and helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polyline cannot be drawn with alpha on itself.
So to make your line drawing code working with alpha, I separated your poyline drawing into several segment drawings.

```
for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) 
{
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(points[i-1].x, points[i-1].y);
    ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

see in action : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TeckelCruel/ne0e840h/1/)

Beware, this code is not performant. To have an efficient code, batching is needed.